# How to resolve Not on FX application thread; currentThread in javafx with swt?

Tags: multithreading, swt, javafx-2, javafx

I am getting error when i try to  call javafx ui from a eclipse job.so i searched through different blog. and i got that  to run javaui i have to run in javafx thread.

```
void run{
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    commanddialog = new CommandloggerDialog(window);
                    commanddialog.open();

                    // javaFX operations should go here

                }
            });
}
```

then i got the error that toolkit is not initialized  .than i came to know that i have to create the toolkit for javafx outside of this thread so 
i modified the method as

```
 Shell shell = new Shell(window.getShell().getDisplay());

        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.None);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                commanddialog = new CommandloggerDialog(window);
                commanddialog.open();

                // javaFX operations should go here

            }
        });

    }
```

here fxcanvas is javafxtoolkit.But after adding all those the previous  error came back. i.e Not on FX application thread;

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The SWT and JavaFX event thread are the same. So you can always use Display.asyncExec when calling from an external thread to the JavaFX UI

Comment: The same exception hit back  after i replaced platform.runlater with display.asyncExec exception:Not on FX application thread;

Comment: All I can say is that you are calling out to FX on a none UI-Thread but without seeing a really runnable code I can't help you more